# Google's Geocode is ignoring the address

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-geocoder, geocode

When inputting the following address into google's geocode API, it seems to be ignoring the street address completely. Searching this address in google works fine.

> *205-9 Nonhyun-dong, Seoul, South Korea*
>
> http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=205-9%20Nonhyun-dong,%20Seoul,%20South%20Korea&sensor=false

It seems to only be the above address that I am having issues with. In the same area, the following address works fine:

> *1306-5 Seocho 4(sa)-dong, Seoul, South Korea*
>
> http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1306-5%20Seocho%204(sa)-dong,%20Seoul,%20South%20Korea&sensor=false

*This problem was originally found in my application and I replicated it using the above URLs

Comment: I can't see how this could be fixed by programming, I think you should contact google for this matter? Have you?

Comment: I just did: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=6579